# Is it possible to check if the name of the sheets is around?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if it is possible to check for a particular sheets for its availability.  If it is around, it will continue on with the rest of the code. If not around then it will add in the sheet.

I have thought of it but it is giving me error. Do share some info if u know something! thanks!

```
sub macro1()
If sheets("Test") = False Then
Sheets.Add.Name = "Test"
End If
'Run my code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets("Test")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = "Test"
    End If

    '~~> Run your code
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks.. That is what i need.. Thank you! Hopefully I can use this to solve the other problem!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach ... create a function that 
- accepts a workbook object and the name of the sheet you're after and
- returns tru if the sheet is found in the workbook

```
Function SheetExists(oWorkbook As Workbook, sSheetname As String)

    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    For Each oWs In oWorkbook.Worksheets
        If oWs.Name = sSheetname Then
            SheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function

Sub TestSheetExists()
    If SheetExists(ActiveWorkbook, "Bob") Then
        MsgBox "Found it"
    Else
        MsgBox "No joy"
    End If
End Sub
```